# Simulate the critical values of Dickey-Fuller test statistic with R

Tags: r, time-series, self-study, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

I am trying to replicate (approximately) the results of the unit root tests described in chapter 17 of Hamilton's book. For the case

\begin{equation}
y_{t}=y_{t-1}+\varepsilon_{t},\ \varepsilon_{t}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)
\end{equation}

with the statistic

\begin{equation}
t=\frac{\hat{\rho}-1}{\hat{\sigma}_{\hat{\rho}}}
\end{equation}

where $\hat{\rho}$ is the usual OLS estimate and $\hat{\sigma}_{\hat{\rho}}$ its standard error.

My question is:

- Is my R code correct? My results are not close to the tabulated values, for example

The critical values of the test with $T=25$ and $\alpha=0.05$ are -2.26 and 2.16. But I get -0.1433872 and 3.2984347

The function simulates $R$ times a random walk of size $T$ and calculates the least squares estimator for each, and their standard error. The resulting distribution should be similar to the tabulated values commonly used.

```
    case1<-function(nob,R){
      R<-1000
      beta.hat<-statistic<-sd.beta<-c()
      for (r in 1:R){
          y<-error<-vector()
          y[1]<-0
          nob<-25
          for (i in 2:nob){
            y[i]<-y[i-1]+rnorm(1,0,1)
          }
          res<-lm(y[2:nob]~Hmisc::Lag(y)[2:nob])
          res.sum <- summary(res)
          statistic[r] <- (res.sum$coefficients[2, 1]-1)/res.sum$coefficients[2,2]
      }
      statistic
    }
    data<-case1(nob=25,R=10000)
    quantile(data, probs=c(0.025,0.975))
    hist(data)
```

Thanks in advance.

[image: Results]

Comment: **1.** Initial values of what matter for what? **2.** Code review is off-topic here, but if you include code, you could also add a few comments to make clear what the code does. **3.** How to address... in which sense "address"? Are you asking about syntax in R?

Comment: I do not agree with the Monte Carlo simulation is off topic. It is a powerful tool widely used by the statistical community.

It is different from using programming tools for data analysis itself.

Comment: Who said Monte Carlo simulation is off topic?

Comment: The Answer to my question is here http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/213589/77970 by @Christoph Hanck