# Generating the ADF test distribution

Tags: time-series, references, simulation, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

I am trying to replicate the distributions for the Dickey-Fuller Unit Root test, but I had no success.

I tried reading the original paper (but explains more of the 70's computing than about the simulation itself) and also following the steps on Enders' "Applied Econometric Time Series" book.

Does anybody have a good source for replicating this simulation? A book? A paper? Code on any language?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213551/how-is-the-augmented-dickey-fuller-test-adf-table-of-critical-values-calculate/213589#213589

Comment: @Helix123 Thanks! This is going to help a lot!